# Microsoft access vba-shift focus from access to word

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating and opening a word document through access 2007 vba. The document is created but the focus is not shifted to word. Instead the focus still remains on access form through which am creating the doc. Below is my code:

```
Dim obj As Word.Application
Dim wor As Word.Document
Dim str As String

str = "C:\hello\folder1\vin.dot"

Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wor = obj.Documents.Add

With wor

 .SaveAs str

 .Close
End With


obj.Visible = True
obj.Documents.Open str

obj.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

Any sugesstions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the focus with AppActivate;

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Word"
```

Comment: Am totally new to this one. Can you please tell me where i need to integrate this part

Comment: Please have a look at the following info:  
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e268a4f4-2c87-4235-a89c-a6c6739f0dae/can-i-activate-a-external-window-in-vba?forum=isvvba  
http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Word/Activatewindowbyname.htm

Comment: Using the AppActivate method with "Microsoft Word" as the argument in my situation (MS Access 2010) caused the following error: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA Word.Application object may have more than one Window associated with it.  You may specify which Window to display by using its Caption property.

Since you created a new Word.Application and only created one Document, you may assume that the 1st element (1-based array) is what you want to display in your code.

```
AppActivate (obj.Windows(1).Caption)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to call the specific window even with other word documents open with the following:

```
Private Sub but_Click()
    'must add tools > references Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library (xx.x is max update)
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    strProjPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path 'get current path
    strVerWord = "test" 'i use this to identify paths that can change based on network configs.
    posOp = InStr(1, strProjPath, strVerWord) ' find the verification word in the path
    strVerPath = "strVerWord filepath\FP\FP\document.docx" 'create string location for document
    strPathPlusDBName = Left(strProjPath, posOp - 1) & strVerPath
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=strPathPlusDBName, ReadOnly:=True)  'open word file in read only
    AppActivate WordDoc
End Sub
```